# AngularJS. Добавление индекса ng-model внутри ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, index, ng-repeat

```
<ol  id="optionsList" class="inputs">
    <li ng-repeat="answer in answers track by $index">
        <textarea ng-cloak class="testVariant" type="text" ckeditor="editorOptionsAnswer" name="option{{$index+1}}" id="option{{$index+1}}" size="80" required ng-model="option{{$index+1}}" ></textarea>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Как сделать чтобы изменялся индекс в `ng-model`, в `name` и `id` все нормально, а с `ng-model` в консоли ошибка

Comment: так ошибка и говорит что именно не правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для простых атрибутов (name, id) вы выполняете выражение {{expression}} во время линковки angular. для angular-атрибутов (ng-model) такой необходимости нет. 
если option это массив то используйте конструкцию

```
ng-model="option[$index+1]"
```

если option* это имена переменных (option1, option2,... optionN), то Вам стоит пересмотреть ваш код и отказаться от такого подхода в пользу массивов или объектов.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Когда подключал веб-редактор СКЕ за пределами ng-repeat модель ng-model была обязательна, и когда подключить два редактора с одинаковыми моделями - текст дублировался в каждом из них. Вот и подумал что нужно добавить индекс модели внутри ng-repeat чтобы модели были разные и не происходил дубляж текста в каждом textarea. Но оказалось что можно всем textarea задать одинаковую модель, например ng-model="option" будет работать и не будет дублировать